# Cant figure out why list filter is not acting correctly

Tags: javascript

Consider this code

```
const b = {
  users: [
    {
      "name": "bob",
      "id": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "sam",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "tom",
      "id": 2
    },
  ]
}

const include = [1]
const c = b.users.filter(user => user.id in include)
console.log(c)
```

In my array `include`, I have the number 1 which references the id in the user object. c should return the "sam" one but instead returns "bob" who has id 0. I'm not understanding why ?

```
 > console.log(c)
 users: [
 {
     "name": "bob",
     "id:" 0
 }]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `in` operator checks whether the given **key** exists in an object.

For example:

```js
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }

console.log('a' in obj) // true
console.log('x' in obj) // false
```

The array `[1]`, when looked at as an object, looks something like `{ 0: 1, length: 1, ... }`.

`0 in [1]` will be true (since `[1][0]` exists - it's the first and only element), but `1 in [1]` will be false (since `[1][1]` doesn't exist, it would be the second element).

To check whether an array contains a certain **value**, you need `Array.prototype.includes`:

```js
const c = b.users.filter(user => include.includes(user.id))
```

Comment: Or keys of array object. OP could run into unexpected behavior using `in` since `0 in [1]` is true

Comment: That's what I described. An array is also an object.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array#includes` instead.

```
const c = b.users.filter(user => include.includes(user.id))
```

Better yet, use the more efficient `Set`.

```
const include = new Set([1])
const c = b.users.filter(user => include.has(user.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const include = [1];
const c = b.users.filter(user =>   include.indexOf(user.id)>=0)
console.log(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the other response,

The reason you get `bob` is that `in` returns true/false if it finds value at the index.

In your `filter`, `user.id in include` returns true if user.id is `0` and false otherwise because your `include` const has a length of 1, and `include[0]` returns `1`.

Have a look at this [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in):

```
// Arrays
let trees = ['redwood', 'bay', 'cedar', 'oak', 'maple']
0 in trees        // returns true
3 in trees        // returns true
6 in trees        // returns false
```

You can see the result produced in your filter, with a console.log:

```
const include = [1]
const c = b.users.filter(user => {
  console.log(user.id in include);
  return user.id in include
  })
console.log(c)
```